# Excel formula to get specific data that according to another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that contains various sheets, each sheet contains different types of orders including items, descriptions, quantity, etc.

```
ITEM    DESCRIPTION    QTY
Apple    ...            1
Orange   ...            4
```

I would like to get a formula that is capable to find out the total quantity of items from every sheet.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in a single cell, I'm afraid the only way of doing so without VBA is to make a manual search over all the pages :

= SUMIF(Page1!A:A,"=ItemName",Page1!C:C)+ SUMIF(Page2!A:A,"=ItemName",Page2!C:C)+ ...

Other solutions would involve you creating your own personal vba function or adding new cells in each sheet which I'm not sure are within the realms of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for  the code, it works but can it be changed so that you only make a change to only one "ItemName" rather than going through each one and change?

Comment: Just replace the name by a field where the name is written, for instance D4 :   = SUMIF(Page1!A:A,"="&D4,Page1!C:C) ...

Comment: No, I mean, for example = SUMIF(Page1!A:A,"=ItemName",Page1!C:C)+ SUMIF(Page2!A:A,"=ItemName",Page2!C:C)+..... Using this code I will have to go through each page and change "itemName". I would like a code that only change one "itemName" and get data from each page. Can you use something like range? For example =SUMIF(page1:page5!A:A, ="ItemName", C:C)?

Answer (score 1):

If all your sheets with "data" on them are the same format, you can save time and maintenance by doing the following:

create a sheet called **start** which is before all the "data" sheets. This sheet should be blank (except perhaps for a bit of text saying "this sheet is intentionally blank")

create a sheet called **end** which is after all the "data" sheets.

Then in your summary sheet, you can do `=SUM(start:end!C:C)` (I'm assuming your quantity is in column C from your example above).

If you use this approach, you can easily add sheets in between **start** and **end**; the formula will not need to be rewritten

Per @l3echod's comment in another answer, you can also use this pattern in SUMIF and SUMIFS formulae, if you want total quantity *per item*:

`=SUMIF(start:end!$A:$A,$A2,start:end!$C:$C)`

this assumes the item in question is in cell A2. Note that depending on the volume of data you have, this might be a slow formula to calculate.